# Citrix XenApp-like terminal services for MacOSX?

Tags: mac-osx, windows-terminal-services

I was wondering if anyone has ever worked with a Citrix XenApp-type terminal services for MacOSX? I want to be able to Virtualize MacOSX desktops and workspaces so that our designers can login to the same workspace anywhere they go. XenApp was the best thing I could think of for Windows machines, but I have no idea how to do this for MacOSX. If anyone has best-practices for saved workspaces on MacOSX that can be accessed from anywhere can chime in that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Aqua Connect might be what you are after - it's a Terminal Server for OS X.

See http://www.aquaconnect.net/